# background image not showing in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, reveal.js, microsoft-edge

I've a problem with a background image used within a div in reveal.js when shown from within Microsoft Edge

this page has the minimum set to show the problem:

https://beta.lookcastapp.com/views/dispatch/campaign/asd908/EnterTitleHere/1

it works as intended on Explorer 11, Chrome, et al.

I checked all the bounding boxes and the div is there as expected and it is not occluded by any other div background

[image: bounding box]

I also tried messing with the url() syntax, adding spaces and quotes and things to no avail

here's a comparative picture from chrome:

[image]

images courtesy of http://lorempixel.com/

Comment: so it's the slideshow rather than the background image thats the problem?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide some more information about your environment. Because I just watched it in my environment and the images just works fine within my IE edge.

Comment: a combination of the two, the same url on another part of the app (the editor) in a div background shows correctly

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Checked version and I was missing an important update on windows. Fill an answer so we can mark this close and dish points around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you perhaps provide some more information about your environment. Because I just watched it in my environment and the images just works fine within my Microsoft Edge